# Typescript: weird type mismatch in react hook forms Control type in custom component library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have created custom component library. One component is responsible for joining material ui and react hook forms using controller. It looks like this:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useController } from "react-hook-form";
import { FieldValues } from "react-hook-form/dist/types";
import { TextFieldProps } from "@mui/material/TextField/TextField";
import ReactHookFormCommonProps from "./ReactHookFormCommonProps";

type JmfFormTextFieldPropsInternal = TextFieldProps;

export type JmfFormTextFieldProps<
    TFieldValues extends FieldValues,
    TContext
> = JmfFormTextFieldPropsInternal &
    ReactHookFormCommonProps<TFieldValues, TContext>;

/**
 * TextField integrated into react-hook-forms.<br>
 * Any other properties are propagated to TextField component https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/
 */
export const JmfFormTextField = <TFieldValues extends FieldValues, TContext>({
    name,
    control,
    errors,
    ...other
}: JmfFormTextFieldProps<TFieldValues, TContext>) => {
    const { field } = useController({ name, control });
    return (
        <TextField
            error={!!errors[name]}
            helperText={`${errors[name]?.message ?? ""}`}
            variant="outlined"
            {...other}
            {...field}
        />
    );
};
```

Reusable react-hook-forms props are defined in its own file

```
import { Control, FieldValues } from "react-hook-form/dist/types";
import { Path } from "react-hook-form";
import { FieldErrors } from "react-hook-form/dist/types/errors";

export default interface ReactHookFormCommonProps<
    TFieldValues extends FieldValues,
    TContext
> {
    /**
     * Name of the react-hook-form field.
     */
    name: Path<TFieldValues>;
    /**
     * Control object of react-hook-form. <br>
     * https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/control
     */
    control: Control<TFieldValues, TContext>;
    /**
     * Errors object of react-hook-form for validations. <br>
     * https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Handleerrors
     */
    errors: FieldErrors<TFieldValues>;
}
```

In the component library project, in story created by storybook tool, the usage is perfectly fine and without errors

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { JmfFormTextField } from "./JmfFormTextField";
import { ComponentMeta, ComponentStory } from "@storybook/react";

export default {
    /*  The title prop is optional.
     * See https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/overview#configure-story-loading
     * to learn how to generate automatic titles
     */
    title: "JmfFormTextField",
    component: JmfFormTextField,
} as ComponentMeta<typeof JmfFormTextField>;

interface FormInputs {
    email: string;
}

export const Primary: ComponentStory<typeof JmfFormTextField> = () => {
    const {
        control,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm<FormInputs>({
        defaultValues: {
            email: "",
        },
    });

    return (
        <JmfFormTextField
            control={control}
            name="email"
            errors={errors}
            type="email"
            label="Email"
            variant="outlined"
        />
    );
};
```

If I use this component library as dependency in other project, I get this error. The usage is same as in story but the project is starting fine. If I use npm link, the project does not start due to this error.

```
TS2322: Type 'import("C:/Users/adamo/WorkSpace/multima/taxguru/frontend/node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/types/form").Control<LoginFormValueTypes, any>' is not assignable to type 'import("C:/Users/adamo/WorkSpace/multima/jmf/frontend/node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/types/form").Control<LoginFormValueTypes, any>'.   Types of property '_updateFieldArray' are incompatible.     Type 'import("C:/Users/adamo/WorkSpace/multima/taxguru/frontend/node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/types/form").BatchFieldArrayUpdate' is not assignable to type 'import("C:/Users/adamo/WorkSpace/multima/jmf/frontend/node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/types/form").BatchFieldArrayUpdate'.       Types of parameters 'updatedFieldArrayValues' and 'updatedFieldArrayValues' are incompatible.         Type 'Partial<FieldArray<TFieldValues, TFieldArrayName>>[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Partial<FieldArray<TFieldValues, ArrayPath<TFieldValues>>>[] | undefined'.           Type 'Partial<FieldArray<TFieldValues, TFieldArrayName>>[]' is not assignable to type 'Partial<FieldArray<TFieldValues, ArrayPath<TFieldValues>>>[]'.             Type 'Partial<FieldArray<TFieldValues, TFieldArrayName>>' is not assignable to type 'Partial<FieldArray<TFieldValues, ArrayPath<TFieldValues>>>'.               Type 'keyof FieldArray<TFieldValues, ArrayPath<TFieldValues>>' is not assignable to type 'keyof FieldArray<TFieldValues, TFieldArrayName>'.                 Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'keyof FieldArray<TFieldValues, TFieldArrayName>'.                   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof FieldArray<TFieldValues, TFieldArrayName>'.                     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.                       Type 'keyof FieldArray<TFieldValues, ArrayPath<TFieldValues>>' is not assignable to type 'never'.                         Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'never'.                           Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.  ReactHookFormCommonProps.d.ts(13, 5): The expected type comes from property 'control' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & JmfFormTextFieldProps<LoginFormValueTypes, any>'
```